# Is it possible to link against .symtab table symbols in an executable file?

Tags: c, linker, elf

Given below main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
  printf("test()\n");
}

int main() {
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Execute below commands:

```
clang-10 main.c -o main
readelf -s main
```

The insetting output is copied here:

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 4 entries:
... ignore ...

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 62 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   61: 00000000004004f0    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 test
```

Question:

1. Is it possible for other relocatable (object file or static library) or shared lib or executable to use/link against/access to the **test** symbol in .symtab table?

Note : Thanks for reviewing the question, this question is only for education purpose, I am not facing a real problem of this.

Edit : 
To export **test** symbol in executable dynamic table:

```
clang-10 main.c -Wl,--dynamic-list=symbols.txt -fPIC -o main

symbols.txt:
{
    test;
};
```

The **test** symbol shows up in the .dymsym table.

Build another shared lib from below source file (shared.c) dependent on above executable **main**:

```
extern void test();

void share() {
  test();
}
```

The build command:

```
clang-10 shared.c main -fPIC -shared -o libShared.so
```

However, the build failed and give below error message:

```
main: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
main: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
main: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
main:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in main(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible

No.

> for other relocatable (object file or static library)

This part of the question is meaningless: link `.o` file against `.symtab` to produce *what*?

If you mean, link an extra `foo.o` into existing executable, the answer is no: `ELF` linkers consider the executable *final*. Most of the information needed to rebuild the executable is discarded after the link, and without that info, breaking the executable apart and rebuilding it again with new code added is near impossible.

There is one linker (on AIX) which allows such break apart and rebuild, but it doesn't use `ELF` format.

> or shared lib

No: dynamic linker can not use `.symtab`. It the symbol to be exported in the dynamic symbol table.

You *could* build your executable with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` flag, and then the function will be present in `.dynsym` and usable by other shared libraries.

> or executable to use/link against/access to the test symbol in .symtab table?

What would it mean to have one executable link against another executable?
They can't be both running in the same process (unless one of them is a position-independent executable, which is really a special form of shared library).

**Update:**

> `clang-10 shared.c main -fPIC -shared -o libShared.so`

Like I said before, you *don't* link against the `main` executable.

The command you are looking for is:

```
clang-10 shared.c -fPIC -shared -o libShared.so
```

This works because shared libraries are (by default) allowed to have unresolved symbols.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.  It is very clear you explain that symbols in executable .symtab are not able to use during the link-editing time.  I will have a look at the suggested ```-Wl,--export-dynamic``` flag.

Comment: I have successfully exported the **text** symbol into the executable's **.dynsym** table, but I am not able to build another shared lib dependent on this executable. I add my build steps in Edit section in the question. Could you kindly give some suggestions how to fix it, please? Thanks a lot. They are able to be fixed by removing **.eh_frame** section and I am not sure if it is a proper way to fix it.

Comment: I am doubting that I have to use dlopen to load the executable at run time in order to use the **test** symbol.

Comment: thanks again. Both relocatable (object/static lib) and shared object are allowed to have undefined symbols, which is a normal compilation process. The intention of this question post is about linking against the exposed symbol in executable's .dymsym table.

Comment: @ZhongkunMa I am sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. See also http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Sorry about misleading you and thanks for sharing the  xyproblem.info. My problem X is :  Is it possible to link against .symtab table symbols in an executable file? The title of this post. As I mentioned in **Note** ,  Thanks for reviewing the question, this question is only for education purpose, I am not facing a real problem of this. This question is just for my curiosity. Thanks again.

Comment: @ZhongkunMa And the answer to your question is "no".